# parallax scrolling image out of view

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm working on a little extracurricular side project to bolster my html5/css3/jquery knowledge and I'm working with Parallax Scrolling but I can't seem to get the bottom image to scroll into view. It seems stuck behind the  above it and no matter what I do I can't seem to pull it down into view.

There should be a giant dollar bill in the bottom black section where it says 'Abe is the money'

my url is : http://www.petegetscreative.com/abe/index.html

inspiration came from this tutorial: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/simple-parallax-scrolling-technique/

cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the dollar bill image is too small.

Looking at [this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/59fnS/1/), when I increase the size of the dollar bill image to 200%, it becomes visible in the preview.

```
#known { 
    background: url(http://www.petegetscreative.com/abe/images/US-$5-SC-1953-Fr.1655.2.jpg) 50% 0 no-repeat fixed;
    background-color: #000;
    background-size: 200%;
    height: 600px;  
    margin: 0 auto; 
    width: 100%; 
    max-width: 1920px; 
    position: relative; 
    padding-top: 50px;
}
```

So what's probably happening is the height of the image is less than the difference in scroll positions. Try a larger (taller) image.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the problem could be the dollar image is less than section tag and the script you're running put the bg image with negative Y position. You can make a test making the image bigger than the 650px ( the section's height ).